# If $F(x)=4x^3 +2x^2 -2ax - 4a^2$ and $F(a) = 0$, find all values of $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I used synthetic division with $x=a$ and since $F(a)=0$, I knew that the last term of synthetic division should be $= 0$. So, I set the last term $(-4a^2 + 4a^3) = 0$ and solved for $a$. This gave me $a=1$ and $a=0$. Online course simply says "incorrect", but won't give the correct answer. Can you show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try a = 1 OR a = 0.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. If you do not want to do synthetic division, just calculate
$$ F(a) = 4a^3 + 2a^2 - 2a\cdot a - 4a^2 = 4a^3 - 4a^2 = 4a^2\cdot (a-1)$$
which is zero only for $a \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer.